# Cancel subsequent fetch requests if the first one fails in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have a component that is being used multiple times for fetching requests asynchronously. I would like to stop fetching if any of the requests fails.
Here is what I have tried:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.url, { signal: this.abortController.signal, headers: this.props.headers })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          createErrorDialog(response);
          this.abortController.abort();
        } else { // do something
               }
       });
 }
```

Comment: By "request fail" do you mean you get a valid response (and go to the `then` of your `fetch`) with `response.ok` set to false or the `fetch` actually raises an error? It looks like you should also be handling the `catch` case of the `fetch` promise.

Comment: I have a catch but in this case it goes to the createErrorDialog function and instead of aborting it goes for the next fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

So if one request fails all components making a request should stop? Then you should pass in your abort controller through props to all your components so they have a common AbortController.

Lets say you are passing in the following:

```
let controller = new AbortController();

<Component abortController={controller}>
```

Then in your Component you want to do something like this:

```
fetch(this.props.url, { signal: this.props.abortController.signal, headers: this.props.headers })
  .then((response) => {
    //do what you need to in here
   })
  .catch(function(e) {
    //abort the controller here
    this.props.abortController.abort();

    //do what you need to do in here with your error
  });
```